# How to restore the original firmware of a router?

Tags: router, troubleshooting, isp, adsl

An internet service provider (ISP) has locked my router and changed its software so that I can not choose another ISP. My router works for that ISP only and it does not work for any Other ISP.

I Downloaded the Original Firmware (Software) from the official site of my router:

http://www.dlinkmea.com/site/index.php/site/productDetails/234

The Original software was an .IMG file

I went to web interface ( GUI ) using the IP : 192.168.1.1

I was looking for "Update software" option on the web interface of my router, but I did not find this option because my ISP has already locked my router as I mentioned before.

Is there a method or a software to install the .IMG file on the Rom of my router ?

I would like to setup the original software directly without accessing the web interface because it has no option to update the software of the router, any Ideas, please?

Router type: DSL-2730U

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would try would be to perform a factory reset of the device. In some cases, factory reset perform a firmware rollback to its original state (Before the ISP firmware). You can follow the guidelines on this page http://www.manualslib.com/manual/593169/D-Link-Dsl-2730u.html?page=17.

If this does not work, I would try a hard reset, usually achieved when a device is reset using the procedure above, then reset again using the same procedure.

After you are back to the original settings, you should upload your own firmware.

Hope this helps.